# Javascript while loop, variable undefined

Tags: javascript

Why does my code not know what random_num1 is outside of the while loop? How do I get my code to know what random_num1 is outside the whole loop?

```js
let valid_input = false;
let input;
let random_num1;
while (!valid_input) {
  let input = Math.round(Number(window.prompt("What should be the maximum number to guess?")));

  if (input != NaN && input > 0) {
    valid_input = true;
    guess_message.innerHTML = `Guess a number between 1 and ${input}`;
  }
  console.log(input);
  let random_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number(input)) + 1;
  console.log(random_num1); // Here the console tells me the random number

}
console.log(random_num1); // Here the console tells me its undefined
```

Comment: I added an answer, you check it out!

Answer (score 0):

At runtime `random_num1` is undefined. Since your code is running synchronously it doesn't wait for the definition in the `while` loop to occur before logging it, even though it appears sequentially after it.

Can read more about [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and variable [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) for more context.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, so how do I fix it? Sorry new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is block scoped. When you assign a value to the variable inside your while loop, it does not change the variable outside that block.

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited to the scope of a block statement, or expression on which it is used, unlike the var keyword, which declares a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. The other difference between var and let is that the latter is initialized to a value only when a parser evaluates it (see below).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#description

Answer (score 0):

just initialize random_num1 to 0 first to begin with, should fix it. Also since you are using direct input from the user as variable input and passing that info to innerHTML on guess_message, poses a security risk. Use textContent instead of innerHTML if you are going to be working with user imput!

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't update the variable outside of the while loop. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You redifine a new variable in your loop.
Try :

```
 random_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*Number(input))+1;
```

Comment: it still doesn't work :/ any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let valid_input = false;
let input = 0;
let random_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number(input)) + 1; // initial value
let finalRandomNumber = undefined; // this will be used to hold the finalValue that you want
console.log("initial random number is", random_num1);
while (!valid_input) {
  let input = Math.round(
    Number(window.prompt("What should be the maximum number to guess?"))
  );

  if (parseInt(Number(input)) > 0) {
    valid_input = true;
    finalRandomNumber = random_num1;
    guess_message.innerHTML = `Guess a number between 1 and ${input}`;
    break;
  }
  console.log("input is", input);
  random_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.abs(Number(input))) + 1;
  console.log("current random number is", random_num1); //Here the console tells me the random number
}
console.log("final result is", finalRandomNumber); //Here the console tells me its undefined
```

Hope this helps. I added some console logs to that you can debug better on your own!